# jQuery click handler sometimes fires twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

I have a toggle list that is used for selection. The problem is that sometimes, the click event on the li elements is fired twice. The toggle on the .config div works fine, but as it's the parent of the list I thought there may be something there. Anyone got an idea of what could be going on here?

HTML:

```
<div class="config">
    <div class="select-list hidden">
        <ul>
            <li>Something 1</li>
            <li>Something 2</li>
            <li>Something 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('body').on('click', '.config', function(e) {
    if (e.target == this) {
        $(this).find('.select-list').toggleClass('hidden');
    } else {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});

$('body').on('click', '.select-list li', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Can you re-create this with a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: Hey, are you the one who posted the answer which is now deleted? I was about to accept that. It worked :)

Comment: Yup. I wasn't able to reproduce it so I was looking for you to create an example on jsFiddle.

Comment: Not able to recreate it on jsFiddle myself. But thank you for your deleted answer. I'll follow up this with the solution later, if you don't want to post your answer again.

Comment: Did my deleted answer help somehow?

Comment: Yes. Fixed the problem.

Comment: OK, I'll undelete my answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your second chunk of code to:

```
$('body').on('click', '.select-list li', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

When you click the list item, the click event is bubbling up the DOM to the .config div and triggering the click event on it, causing the toggleClass to occur again.

Comment: Isn't the conditionnal `e.target == this` blocking this? If he click on `li`, `e.target` is the `li` and `this` is still `.config`?

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but this fixed the problem. Thank you for your answer.